# Is the space of subprobability measures weakly sequentially closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space, $\mathcal M(E)$ denote the space of finite signed measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $\mathcal M_{\le1}$ denote the subset of those $\mu\in\mathcal M(E)$ which satisfy $0\le\mu\le1$.

> If $\tau$ denotes the topology generated by the weak convergence on $\mathcal M(E)$, are we able to show that $\mathcal M_{\le1}(E)$ is sequentially $\tau$-closed?

Given $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal M_{\le1}(E)$ weakly converging to $\mu\in\mathcal M(E)$, we need to show $\mu\in\mathcal M_{\le1}(E)$.

*Thoughts*:

(a) Let $\nu=\nu^+-\nu^-$ denote the Jordan decomposition of $\nu\in\mathcal M(E)$ and $|\nu|:=\nu^++\nu^-$. If $(\nu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal M(E)$ and $(\nu_n^\pm)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ weakly converges to $\nu_{\pm}\in\mathcal M(E)$ with $\nu_{\pm}\ge0$, it obviously follows that $(\nu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ weakly converges to $\nu_+-\nu_-$ and $(|\nu_n|)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ weakly converges to $\nu_++\nu_-$.

(BTW: If we define $\nu:=\nu_+-\nu_-$, does it necessarily follow that $\nu^\pm=\nu_\pm$? I guess not ... We can simply take $\nu_+=\nu_-$ to see that this is wrong)

(b) However, unless I'm missing something, if $(\eta_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal M(E)$ weakly converges to $\eta\in\mathcal M(E)$, it seems like it doesn't necessarily follow that $(\eta_n^\pm)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ weakly converges to $\eta^\pm$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: By "weak convergence", you mean convergence when tested against bounded continuous functions?

Comment: JochenGlueck Yes, I mean the locally convex topology induced by the duality pairing $$\langle f,\mu\rangle:=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu\;\;\;\text{for }(f,\mu)\in C_b(E)\times\mathcal M(E).$$

Comment: Thanks for you reply. And the condition $\mu \le 1$ should probably replaced with the function that $\mu(E) \le 1$, right? (Since there is no element "$1$" in $\mathcal{M}(E)$).

Comment: @JochenGlueck I'm considering $\mu$ as a function $\mathcal B(E)\to\mathbb R$ and hence $\mu\le1$ means that for all $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ it holds $\mu(B)\le1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly then $\int fd\mu \geq 0$ for all $f \in C_b^{+}(E)$ and this implies that $\mu$ is a positive measure. Clearly $\mu (E)=\lim \mu_n(E) \leq 1$. So the answer is YES.

Comment: I'v deleted my answer since I just noted that yours was a few minutes earlier :-). Anyway, it might be worthwhile to mention that this argument actually shows that the set of subprobability measures is even $\tau$-closed (and not only sequentially $\tau$-closed).

Comment: @JochenGlueck You could undelete your answer since it has an additional information.

Comment: Agreed; I've done so.

Comment: Does the weak convergence of $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ necessarily imply the weak convergence of the total variations $(|\mu_n|)_{n\in\mathbb N}$?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the set of sub-probability measures is even $\tau$-closed (and thus, it is inparticular, sequentially $\tau$-closed). This follows from the following two observations (which are essentially the same arguments as used in Kavi Rama Murthy' answer):

- A measure $\mu \in \mathcal{M}(E)$ satisfies $\mu \ge 0$ if and only if $\langle \mu, f\rangle \ge 0$ for all $0 \le f \in C_b(E)$.
- A measure $0 \le \mu \in \mathcal{M}(E)$ satisfies $\mu(E) = \langle \mu, 1 \rangle$, where $1 \in C_b(E)$ denotes the constant function with values $1$.

Comment: How exactly do you derive the $\tau$-closedness?. I'm not an expert in general topology, but as far as I remember, "a set $A$ is closed if and only if the limit of every convergent net in $A$ is contained in $A$" does not hold.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: We can consider nets rather than sequences. A set $A$ is closed if and only if for each net in $A$ that converges to a point $x$ we have $x \in A$. (That's true for general topological spaces.)

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Alternatively, we can write $\mathcal{M}_{\le 1}(E)$ as an intersection of the closed sets $\{\mu \in \mathcal{M}(E): \, \langle \mu, f \rangle \ge 0\}$ over all $0 \le f \in C_b(E)$ and the closed set $\{\mu \in \mathcal{M}(E): \, \langle \mu, 1 \rangle \le 1 \}$. (All these sets are closed since they are pre-images of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$ under continuous functions.)

Comment: Do you have a reference for the equivalence in your first comment?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: It's a standard fact in topology. For instance, in "Pedersen: Analysis Now (1988)" it is proved in Proposition 1.3.6 that a point $x$ is in the closure of $A$ if and only if there exists a net in $A$ that converges to $x$. This immediately implies the equivelance that I mentioned ("$\Rightarrow$": If $A$ is closed and a net in $A$ converges to $x$, then $x$ in the closure of $A$ by the reference, so $x \in A$. "$\Leftarrow$:" Let $x$ be in the closure of $A$. By the reference, there exists a net in $A$ that converges to $x$, and by assumption, this implies $x \in A$.).

Comment: By the way, Wikipedia has a surprisingly good coverage of point set topology (which is, of course, not in general the case for each mathematical topic). For instance, the equivalence we discussed is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Properties).

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Ouch, now I just noted that I had completely overlooked the second sentence of your first comment. After reading it now, my first comment seems to be completely out of context (it's, of course, ridiculous that I mention nets as if they were new to you, after you have already mentioned them before). Had I noticed this second sentence in your comment before, I would of course have provided a reference from the very beginning. My apologies; that's really embarrassing.